# Inside/outside test of any point on 2D plane?

Tags: mathematics, computer-engineering, computer-aided-design, geometry

Suppose I have one plane $Ax+By+Cz+D=0.$ I want to test $(x, y, z)$ is inside of this plane or outside.

**My attempt:1** Then draw normal N on that plane which point away from the observer [Image1.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y0nVH.jpg)

If $Ax+By+Cz+D>0$
or $(-A)x+(-B)y+(-C)z+(-D)<0$ then $(x, y, z)$ is outside of the plane.

And if $Ax+By+Cz+D<0$
or $(-A)x+(-B)y+(-C)z+(-D)>0$ then $(x, y, z)$ is inside of the plane.

**My attempt:2** Now draw the normal N on that plane which point towards the observer [image2.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XfZ7I.jpg)

If $Ax+By+Cz+D<0$
or $(-A)x+(-B)y+(-C)z+(-D)>0$ then $(x, y, z)$ is outside of the plane.

And if $Ax+By+Cz+D>0$
or $(-A)x+(-B)y+(-C)z+(-D)<0$ then $(x, y, z)$ is inside of the plane.

My question is my both attempts are right? Can anybody help me to understand.

Comment: PLease edit per the comments to explain what you mean by "inside/outside" .

Comment: Inside mean behind and outside mean front of observer.

Comment: Cross-posted: https://engineering.stackexchange.com/q/48636/7678, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4325904/14578.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if a point is in a plane it means if you plug in x.y,z in the plains EQ. you get zero. And if you get nonzero the point is not in the plane.

Maybe I am not understanding your question. If you can rephrase your question I may get it.

Comment: If I say Ax+By+Cz+D>0 then (x, y, z) is the outside of the plane and then (−A)x+(−B)y+(−C)z+(−D)<0 indicates (x, y, z) **inside** of the plane or **outside** of the plane or both depending upon implementation?

Comment: both mean not in the plane. only zero answer is in the plane.

Comment: inside mean behind the plane and outside mean front of the plane

Comment: *behind* and *front* imply that there is a viewer involved. It is not clear on which side of the plane the viewer is placed.